# WxWidgets custom events

Tags: c++, events, wxwidgets

I'm trying to use a **custom event** in my **WxWidgets** C++ application, like described [here](http://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Custom_Events#.22But_I_don.27t_need_a_whole_new_event_class....22).

In the constructor of my wxApp:

```
Connect(wxID_ANY, wxCommandEventHandler(APP::OnMyEvent));
```

Then the function that should catch the event:

```
void APP::OnMyEvent(wxCommandEvent& event)
{
    exit(0); //testing
}
```

Finally, to test it:

```
wxCommandEvent MyEvent(wxEVT_COMMAND_BUTTON_CLICKED); 
wxPostEvent(this, MyEvent);
```

I launch the thing...but it seems that the event is not posted or not caught.

Does someone understand this behaviour ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appear to be using the following overload of [Connect](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/stable/wx_wxevthandler.html#wxevthandlerconnect):

```
void Connect(wxEventType eventType, wxObjectEventFunction function, 
    wxObject* userData = NULL, wxEvtHandler* eventSink = NULL)
```

If so, then should an event of type `wxID_ANY` happen (never?), then the connected function will be called.

Perhaps you need:

```
Connect(wxEVT_COMMAND_BUTTON_CLICKED, wxCommandEventHandler(APP::OnMyEvent));
```

Comment: Excellent, it works perfectly, thank you :) I thought wxID_ANY would be any kind of event... It is not the case ?

Comment: Added a link to the documentation. You won't get away without telling which type of event you want to handle. The `id` should be an identifier of the widget from which the event came from. (E.g let this function handle events of type `wxEVT_...` which came from a widget with a particular (or any) identifier.

Comment: If you have anything to say about my question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4037525/wxwidgets-2-9-custom-events) I would appreciate it.