# wxWidgets 2.9 custom events

Tags: c++, events, wxwidgets

I appear to have followed [this example (found under "Defining Your Own Event Class")](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/overview_events.html), and my code compiles and runs without error, but I'm not catching the event anywhere.

The code:

```
class MyCustomEvent : public wxEvent
{
//... stuff here
};
wxDEFINE_EVENT(MY_CUSTOM_EVENT_1,MyCustomEvent);
```

and later I bind the event:

```
Bind(MY_CUSTOM_EVENT_1, &MyApp::OnProcessCustom, this);
```

and later I throw an event of that type:

```
MyCustomEvent* eventCustom = new MyCustomEvent(MY_CUSTOM_EVENT_1);
eventCustom->SetEventObject(this);
this->QueueEvent(eventCustom); //this is MyApp
```

Unfortunately, after the event is thrown, it's never caught by OnProcessCustom.

Any ideas?

*Note: Similar, but not the same as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709124/wxwidgets-custom-events).*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks correct so the problem is probably in the part you're not showing. Just notice that don't need to pass `this` as last argument to `Bind()` if you're calling it from a MyApp method.

I'd also advise looking at the event sample, it has working code defining a custom event (albeit using `wxCommandEvent` instead of a custom class but you can easily modify it to use your class instead).

Comment: Indeed the error must be in the surrounding code.  Somehow I was able to get a more complicated example with a templated event class working but this is still buggy.  Unfortunately no time to really figure out the problem.