# wxwidgets custom event won't propagate to the parent window

Tags: c++, visual-c++, wxwidgets

I tried to implement to implement my own custom event. It does work if I post it from the class i connected it from (a wxFrame) but if it gets posted from a child wxFrame it doesn't get catched.

The Custom event:

```
**cFrameFocus.h**
#pragma once
#include <wx\event.h>
class cFrameFocusEvent;
const wxEventTypeTag<cFrameFocusEvent> evtFRAME_FOCUS( wxNewEventType() );
//eventhandler macro
#if _MSC_VER <= 1600
typedef void (wxEvtHandler::*MyFrameFocusEventFunction)(cFrameFocusEvent&);
#define FrameFocusEventHandler(func) wxEVENT_HANDLER_CAST(MyFrameFocusEventFunction,func)
#else
#define FrameFocusEventHandler(func) (&func)
#endif
class cFrameFocusEvent :
    public wxEvent
{
    wxWindow* m_frame;
public:
    cFrameFocusEvent(wxEventType pEventType,int pWinId = wxID_ANY,const wxWindow* pWin = 0);
    ~cFrameFocusEvent(void);
    //impement base class pure virtual
    virtual wxEvent* Clone(void)const;
    //accessor
    wxWindow* GetWindow(void)const;
};

**cFrameFocus.cpp**
#include "cFrameFocus.h"
cFrameFocusEvent::cFrameFocusEvent(wxEventType pEventType,int pWinId,const wxWindow* pWin):
wxEvent(pWinId,pEventType)
{
    m_frame = const_cast<wxWindow*>(pWin);
}
cFrameFocusEvent::~cFrameFocusEvent(void)
{
}
wxEvent* cFrameFocusEvent::Clone(void)const{
    return new cFrameFocusEvent(*this);
}
wxWindow* cFrameFocusEvent::GetWindow(void)const{
    return m_frame;
}
```

The child Frame trying to send an even :

```
cFrameFocusEvent* pevent = new cFrameFocusEvent(evtFRAME_FOCUS,GetId(),this);
wxQueueEvent(GetParent(),pevent);
```

Note: I did already stumble upon this question [wxWidgets 2.9 custom events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4037525/wxwidgets-2-9-custom-events), but it didn't help me.

Comment: I think you need to derive from `wxCommandEvent` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to read [event propagation overview](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/overview_events.html#overview_events_propagation) to understand how the events work in wxWidgets. In particular, it would have told you that only events deriving from `wxCommandEvent` are propagated upwards by default, for the other ones you need to call `ResumePropagation(N)` to make them propagate `N` levels up (and could be `INT_MAX` to make them propagate without limit, of course).

Comment: thanks for for the quick response. I tried it now by deriving it from wxCommandEvent (because it propagates upwards by default as you sad). Sadly it still doesn't work

Comment: You don't show the code handling the event, so my guess is that the problem is there. I'd advise you to look at the event sample included in wxWidgets distribution, it shows how to define and send and catch a simple custom command event, your code above looks rather strange to me.

Comment: actually the mistake lies in the code i supplied. I will post the answer right below yours

Answer (score 1):

After some intensive debugging and study of the wxWidgets code I figured it out.
The problem is that with every include of the file "cFrameFocus.h" the wxEventTypeTag changed (the id of it), which meant that when it got included in a file to connect to this event type id had the id "x" and in a different file to post this event the event type had the id "y".
The solution to this wasn't a matter of propagation (since it got anyway sent to the level 0, where it should be processed), rather a "programming mistake".

```
**cFrameFocus.h**
extern const wxEventTypeTag<cFrameFocusEvent> evtFRAME_FOCUS;

**cFrameFocus.cpp**
const wxEventTypeTag<cFrameFocusEvent> evtFRAME_FOCUS(wxNewEventType());
```

this code change fixed the error

**EDIT**

As VZ mentioned in the comments, it is more appropriate to use the macros and not directly accessing the functions.

The proper solution:

```
***cFrameFocus.h***
```

wxDECLARE_EVENT(evtFRAME_FOCUS,cFrameFocusEvent);

```
***cFrameFocus.cpp***
 wxDEFINE_EVENT(evtFRAME_FOCUS,cFrameFocusEvent);
```

Comment: This is why you should use `wxDECLARE_EVENT(evtFRAME_FOCUS, cFrameFocusEvent)` and `wxDEFINE_EVENT(evtFRAME_FOCUS, cFrameFocusEvent)` macros instead of doing it manually. Not only do they isolate you from any possible future changes in event type internals, but they also clearly indicate that one can/should be only used in the header (it's a declaration) and another in the source file (it's a definition).

Comment: I did try it with the macro as well, but it did not change the situation. Just like in the documentation stated. The only difference until now was that the example implementation was in a single file (all of it, from the wxApp to everything else), and mine is not. it seems without the "extern" declaration it won't work, if the file gets included more than once

Comment: But `extern` **is** inside the macro, that's the whole point.

Comment: I see. thanks for your patience and for your always magnificent answers.

Comment: This is so helpful!  The wxWidgets Programming Guide doesn't explain using wxDECLARE_EVENT in its custom event type example.